# robust algorithm for surface reconstruction from 3D point cloud?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I am trying to figure out what algorithms there are to do surface reconstruction from 3D range data. At a first glance, it seems that the *Ball pivoting algorithm* (**BPA**) and *Poisson surface reconstruction* are the more established methods?

- What are the established, more robust algorithm in the field other than BPA and Poisson surface reconstruction algorithm?
- Recommended research publications?
- Is there available source code?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I have been facing this dilemma for some months now, and made exhaustive research.

## Algorithms

Mainly there are 2 categories of algorithms: computation geometry, and implicit surfaces.

### Computation Geometry

They fit the mesh on the existing points.

Probably the most famous algorithm of this group is [powercrust](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/sm.pdf), because it is theoretically well-established - it guarantees watertight mesh.

Ball Pivoting is patented by IBM. Also, it is not suitable for pointclouds with varying point density.

### Implicit functions

One fits implicit functions on the pointcloud, then uses a marching-cube-like algorithm to extract the zero-set of the function into a mesh.

Methods in this category differ mainly by the different implicit functions used.

[Poisson](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/MyPapers/ISVC09.pdf), [Hoppe's](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/proj/thesis/), and [MPU](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.8.2916) are the most famous algorithms in this category. If you are new to the topic, i recommend to read Hoppe's thesis, it is very explanatory.

The algorithms of this category usually can be implemented so that they are able to process huge inputs very efficiently, and one can scale their quality<->speed trade-off. They are not disturbed by noise, varying point-density, holes. A disadvantage of them is that they require consistently oriented surface normals at the input points.

## Implementations

You will find small number of free implementations. However it depends on whether You are going to integrate it into free software (in this case GPL license is acceptable for You) or into a commercial software (in this case You need a more liberal license). The latter is very rare.

One is in [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/). I suspect it to be difficult to integrate (no documentation is available for free), it has a strange, over-complicated architecture, and is not designed for high-performance applications. Also has some limitations for the allowed input pointclouds.

Take a look at [this](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/) Poisson implementation, and after that share your experience about it with me please.

Also: 
[here](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/) are a few high-performance algorithms, with surface reconstruction among them.

CGAL is a famous 3d library, but it is free only for free projects.
[Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) is a famous application with GPL.

Also (Added August 2013):
The library [PCL](http://pointclouds.org) has a [module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__surface.html) dedicated to surface reconstruction and is in active development (and is part of Google's Summer of Code). The surface module contains a number of different algorithms for reconstruction. PCL also [has the ability](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php) to estimate surface normals, incase you do not have them provided with your point data, this functionality can be found in the features [module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__features.html). PCL is released under the terms of the BSD license and is open source software, it is free for commercial and research use.

Comment: thanks for sharing all you review work, great answer. Busy with other stuff at the moment, but I'll get back to you once I get the time to evaluate the algorithms/code you provided.

Comment: CGAL 4.0 is now completely under GPL/LGPL.  See [here](http://www.cgal.org/license.html).

Comment: You may also be interested in [A Benchmark for Surface Reconstruction](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~bergerm/recon_bench/) which is a SIGGRAPH paper that include source code, at least some of which is BSD license.

Comment: I have played with the AdaptiveSolvers. The package looks great and includes cleaning of the extrapolated vertices. So a similar response here too:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56663/how-to-extract-a-smooth-contour-from-a-set-of-points-in-3d/56664?noredirect=1#comment114064_56664

Answer (score 14):

If you want make some direct experiments with various surface reconstruction algorithms you should try  **[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net)**, the mesh-processing system, it is open source and it contains implementations of many of the previously cited surface reconstruction algorithms, like:

- Poisson Surface Recon
- a couple of MLS based approach,
- a ball pivoting implementation
- a variant of the Curless volume based approach
- Delaunay based techniques (Alpha shapes and Voronoi filtering)
- tools for computing normals from scattered point sets
- and many other tools for comparing/measuring/cleaning/simplifying the resulting meshes.

Sources are protected by GPL, so you could not use them in a commercial closed source project, but it is very important to get the right feeling about the properties of the various surface reconstruction algorithms (how sensitive to noise they are, the speed, the robustness to outliers, how they preserve fine details etc etc) before starting to implement one of them.

Comment: I have found [this blog post](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/meshing-point-clouds.html) and the comments below it to provide good hints.

Answer (score 5):

You might start looking at some recent work in the field - currently something like [Fast low-memory streaming MLS reconstruction of point-sampled surfaces](http://www.crs4.it/vic/cgi-bin/bib-page.cgi?id='Cuccuru:2009:FLM') by Gianmauro Cuccuru, Enrico Gobbetti, Fabio Marton, Renato Pajarola, and Ruggero Pintus.  Its citations can get you going through the literature pretty quickly.

Comment: Nice, up-to-date paper that I hadn't come across before. Like the Related Eork section. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Paul, I didn't know this paper. And I love 2 authors are clearly from Sardinia :P

Answer (score 4):

While not a mesh representation, an ex-colleague recommended me this link
to source code for a Thin Plate Spline method:

[Link](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/tpsdemo/index.html)

Anyone tried it?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's exactly right for your case, since it seems weird that you omitted it, but [marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) is commonly mentioned in cases like these.

Comment: thanks, I am still in an exploring stage of the subject, haven't heard of marching cubes before - will check out.

Comment: marching cubes isn't ideal for surface points, it's expensive to work out if you are inside the volume or not.

Answer (score 3):

As I had this problem too, I did develop and implement my own point cloud crust algorithm. The sources, as well as the documentation, can be found on github.com: https://github.com/meixxi/PointCloudCrust. The algorithm is implemented in Java.

Maybe, this can help you. You can find also a short python script on the page which illustrates how to use the library. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! This is quite a clean implementation and very easy to understand. A bit slow. I've managed to port it to cpp.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mesh-processing-library) on GitHub, is a open source [Mesh Processing Library](https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/Mesh-processing-library/master/README.html) in C++ by [Dr. Hugues Hoppe](http://hhoppe.com/), in which the surface reconstruction program **Recon** is a good option for your problem...

Comment: This is just terribly documented.

Answer (score 1):

There is [3D Delaunay tool by Geometric Tools](https://www.geometrictools.com/Samples/Geometrics.html#Delaunay3D). This tool is used DirecX and OpenGL.  Unfortunately, you may need buy a book to see actual example code of the library. You still read the code and figure out.

Matlab also introduced a surface reconstruction tool using Delaunay, [delaunayTriangulation class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Alpha Shapes](http://biogeometry.duke.edu/software/alphashapes/index.html).