# Is there an algorithm that, given a point cloud, infers an optimal wireframe (surface) structure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, surface

I have a point cloud that I would like to convert to a surface, in the form of a wireframe lattice structure.

This means, from a sequence of 3D points *(x,y,z)*, obtaining three 2D matrices *X,Y,Z* of the same size. In this way the points should be topologically related with a neighborhood of 4 (North, South, East, West). Such an organization of the points might, then, be plotted with functions such as *matplotlib*'s [`Axes3D.plot_wireframe`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots) or [`Axes3D.plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface)

From what I understood, the relationship of a point with the neighboring points is characterized by having minimal distance. I think that this is a combinatorial optimization problem, and NP-hard.

Now the question: are there algorithms that, given a list of 3D points, return the three aforementioned matrices X,Y,Z ?

Thank you very much. I also hope this is the correct stack exchange forum for this kind of question.

Comment: This is probably better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn't *programmers* a stack exchange mostly for software engineering, design patterns and development practices, and quite off-topic with regards of algorithms for mathematical applications?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's better suited to "pre-coding" questions; SO tends to be for when you're implementing. Maybe look at the CompSci site?

Comment: Thanks! Just X-posted :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [robust algorithm for surface reconstruction from 3D point cloud?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud)

Answer (score 3):

Your task has a name, it's called Surface Reconstruction. Google it for details and overviews.
If you use PCL then here is a good overview ending with code samples: http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/icra2012/surface.pdf

Another good library capable to deal with this task I know of is CGAL, see http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not an expert I think you need to calculate a convex hull on your point cloud first,
and then do a Delaunay triangulation on the convex hull to get a wireframe.
Scipy has provisions to calculate convex hulls and triangulations.

Comment: Thinking back about what I wrote, I think the convex hull may conceal some of the detail in your data. Perhaps better find an expert :)