# 3D surface morphing

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

Let's say I have a cloud of 3D points which represent some objects in front of me. I'd like to find a 3D surface which can fit these points in an acceptable way. Problem is, there could be a lot of gaps between points, so I was thinking to start from a planar surface and move this surface toward the points, so that in the end the planar surface would be deformed into the surface I was looking for. Is there a  specific technical name for this kind of technique, and are there some libraries which can achieve this?

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html

Comment: Google "deformable surface".

Comment: I know to terms for this techniques: "surface reconstruction" and "manifold learning". I'm not familiar with the latter. For the former check out CGAL, PCL, MeshLab, etc

Comment: also see answers for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud