# How to convert vtkPolyData to itkImage?

Tags: vtk, itk

I've set of vtk polygonal data files for segmented vessels:-

---

[image: vessel_1]
[image: vessel_2]

---

How to (voxelize) convert it to itk image with specific (size, origin and spacing)?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial problem. It is not possible to do that given your *raw* contours. If you can convert your contours to a closed surface, then you can use vtkVoxelModeller to create a vtkImage. Then you can create an itk image using vtkITKImageFilter.

Alternatively, you can fit a closed geometry to your contours and create voxels based on the parameterization of your geometry:
http://www.mit.edu/~adalca/files/papers/nerve_segmentation.pdf

Comment: But, how to convert those contours to a closed surface?

Comment: There are lots of ways of constructing a surface from point clouds. I won't list them in detail, since this has already been answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud