# Surface approximation based on RBF

Tags: c++, surface, approximation

I am looking for a way of approximating a surface based on a set of 3D data points. For this purpose I would like to use a method based on radial basis functions but I cannot find a free implementation in C++.
I looked in ITK, VTK and open CV but I did not find anything...

Does anyone knows a free implementation of such an algorithm ?

Any suggestion about the reconstruction of a surface based on a set of 3D data points is also more than welcome ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D surface reconstruction can be challenging.  I would first recommend taking a look at [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/).  The Point Cloud Library has grown into a nice set of tools for 3D point management and interpretation, and its license and API sound compatible with your needs.  The [surface reconstruction features](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__surface.html) of the library appear to be most applicable. In fact, [RBF reconstruction](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_marching_cubes_r_b_f.html) is supported.

If PCL doesn't work, there are other options:

1. [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/),
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud) SO post provides a nice summary, and
3. of course, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud) provides some links

Finally, you might search [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index), Google Scholar, etc. for papers like this [one](http://www-lb.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2005/cmsc828v/papers/siggraph01.pdf).  As an example, a search for "3D Surface Reconstruction" at CiteSeerX yields *many* hits.  RBF-based reconstruction is just one of many methods: is your application truly limited to radial basis functions?  If not, there are many choices, (i.e. Ball Pivoting Algorithm).  See [this](https://www.academia.edu/3150371/Surface_Reconstruction_Algorithms_Review_and_Comparison) survey paper for some comparisons.