# Projection of points on plane and the inverse transformation

Tags: math, 3d, linear-algebra

i'm working on a project where i have a cloud of points in space as input data, my goal is to create a surface.

I started by computing a regression plan for the cloud, then i projected my points on the plane using dot products :

My plane is represented by a point and a normal , i construct the axis of the plane's space using cross products then project each point on these axis.

then i triangulate in 2D (that's the point of the whole operation).

My problem is that my points now are in the plane space and i want to get them back to their inital position (inverse the transformation) to have my surface ON my points.

thank you :)

Comment: You lose spatial information when you do a 3D-to-2D projection. There _is no_ inverse.

Comment: Just save the corresponding originals (via indices).

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud

Comment: thank you for your answers , the best way to do it is saving the indices but i had to change my data structures as i wasn't using indices and i thought maybe there was "a trick" but yeah :) cheers every one

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to keep the original positions and make the triangulation give you the indices rather than the positions , i hope it will help !